# Is it "a book from a (or) the course"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> A: What is that book you are reading?
>
> B: Just a book from ***(a/the)*** course.

The situation is a friend of mine saw me reading something and I just want to state that it was ***just one of the books from one of the courses that I took*** and ***I don't want to expand on which course is it***. "a' sounds more fit for my intention but is it grammatically correct to use "a" there?

Comment: You probably might want to say "Just a book from a course I took [last semester]". "Just a book from one of my courses," seems fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just a book from ***a*** course.

**The**, a definite article, refers to something that is known by both the speaker and the listener. It implies that Person A knows which course you are talking about. Your question makes clear that this is not the case.

If, however, Person A does indeed know which course you are talking about, then it would be proper to answer

> Just a book from ***the*** course.

It would be common to add *I'm taking* to the end of "Just a book from ***a*** course."

Comment: As to your last point, one could also add "I took," if the course is over and done with.

Comment: Upvote, good point, however if OP is carrying the book, she is probably still taking the course. Do you remember how heavy textbooks are?

Comment: Sure I do. But I also see college bookstores selling e-readers nowadays :^)

Answer (score 0):

A is used when whatever is being talked about isn't specific and the is used for something that is specific and also referred to directly for example:

Compare:
I really like the cake you have made.= The cake being talked about here might be right before the speaker and there might only be one cake or more, but the speaker is focusing on one particular one.

I really like a cake you have made.= Here there may be many more cakes and the speaker might have one particular one in mind but be talking about just one of the many.

Comment: Wouldn't _I really like a cake you have made_ sound a bit odd? and should be changed to _I really like one of the cakes you have made_? or It is just totally fine for native speaker?

Comment: It could be said using either one of your suggestions, but how suitable it sounds depends on the context, and yes the second one does sound better.